# pandas.errors.InvalidIndexError: Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes with unique indexes:

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'a':[4,6,3,0], 'b':[5,6,3,9], 'c':[4,3,6,6]}, index=['a1','a2','a3','a4'])

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'a':[10,5,13,10], 'b':[52,61,33,19], 'c':[14,23,36,16]}, index=['b1','b2','b3','b4'])
```

However, when I concat the two dataframes as follows:

```
df = pd.concat([df1,df2])
```

I get the following error:

```
pandas.errors.InvalidIndexError: Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects
```

I am not sure what is going on here. Can someone point me to what I am doing wrong.

Comment: No error from my side by using your data

Comment: I think you need [pd.merge()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) rather than concat

Comment: @KevOMalley743 no what I need is concat because I don't need any sort of join. I want to append.

Comment: Ok sorry about that, I also ran your code and got no errors. Can you give a little more info on the system and ide that you're using.

Comment: @OP, your code works perfectly fine for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So for purposes of demo'ing what I was doing I posed the above to represent my data (proprietary data) and the challenge I was facing. It turned out that the sample above works so it wasn't a good representation. The actual problem has over 100 dataframes.

Anyway I figured the issue was due to some dataframes having empty columns. Once I dropped the empty columns in those dataframes, everything worked fine.

Thanks!